# z-index issue on Chrome (Android 4.1)

Tags: android, google-chrome, z-index, viewport

Found a strange bug with Chrome on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.1.1 (doesn't happen on the old android browser)

If you view [Test with viewport meta tag](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6910873/android-test/test1.html) (contents pasted below) you'd expect the #container to move above #header as it has a higher z-index but it goes below it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Android Bug?</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { padding: 0; }
        #header {
            background: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 230px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        #container {
            background: blue;
            padding: 500px 0;
            margin-bottom: 1000px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 200;
            top: 230px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove the viewport meta tag then it works as expected [Test without viewport meta tag](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6910873/android-test/test2.html)

Does anyone know if there is a reason that this is happening or is it a bug in Chrome/Android?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior in Galaxy Nexus running 4.1. Can you provide a screenshots, and if it still reproduces include your device info, screenshots and details as a bug via http://new.mcrbug.com

Answer (score 1):

This is an Android bug with the default broswer. It occurs on a number of devices (including my Maxx with 4.0.4), not sure what the full list of devices is.

It's effected by the fixed position though. Although this changes the layout of your site, setting the header to position:absolute; will ensure that the z-index is respected.

At least for mobile, some older iOS devices don't always respect fixed position elements anyway so that's something to consider.